# How did Trinity get her powers in The Matrix Resurrections?

Tags: the-matrix

How did she get her powers? Was it transferred to her by Neo?

Comment: Remember that the Matrix has always ever been just a computer simulation which can be manipulated such as producing an infinite locker of guns, or brain-jacking superhuman kung fu abilities. People can fly in the Matrix simulation the same way in our world a computer programmer might program a Trinity character in a Matrix game to fly. In the Matrix’s case, some characters are able to program these powers themselves on the fly.

Comment: sudo dd if=/dev/neo of=/dev/trinity

Comment: ***Spoilers:*** I believe she got her powers because the machines used both Neo and Trinity to power the new Matrix and they are strongly connected to each other, so they share the same powers (but maybe discovering and using them separately in the story) and possibly share the same source code. Their connection/love and the Matrix itself make them even stronger. Another possibility is that they both are "The One" now.

Comment: FYI I removed the unnecessary/overly specific tag.

Comment: There was never a "One". It was always a "Two". At least that's what I took of it after watching the movie. No evidence, that's why I just put it as a comment.